# How to suppres the warming "Mehtod 'XXXX' recurses infinitely"

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

When I use method swizze to hook some method. The original name of method :

```
- (void)printOutMessage:(NSString*)message;
```

My hook method:

```
- (void)shzPrintOutMessage:(NSString*)message;
```

The implementation of my hook method:

```
- (void)shzPrintOutMessage:(NSString *)message {
//Do some thing I like
    [self shzPrintOutMessage:message];
}
```

Now,I received the warming:Mehtod 'shzPrintOutMessage:' recurses infinitely. How can I suppress the kind of this warming?

Comment: You could not recurse infinitely.  When swizzling, you need to save a reference to the original method implementation and then call it from the replacement.  You don't want to call the replacement implementation itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do as bellow might be work for you.

**Define strMsg**

```
- (void)shzPrintOutMessage:(NSString *)message {
//Do some thing I like
     self->strMes = message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Winfinite-recursion"
- (void)shzPrintOutMessage:(NSString *)message {
    // Do some thing I like
    [self shzPrintOutMessage:message];
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```